# How to properly obtain a full list of my subscribers using the Youtube API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, youtube-api

I'm trying to use Google's Youtube API (specifically the `youtube.subscriptions.list` endpoint) to obtain a full list of channelIDs that are subscribed to me.  I've got authentication working, and I'm even receiving a list of 40 subscribers each time I make the request.  However, I have over 100 subscribers so the request is returning less than half of them.  I figured it might be some sort of privacy options that some users had enabled that was preventing me from getting their data.  However, I've made plenty of new accounts and fiddled with the privacy settings and they refuse to show up in the list of 40 subscribers.

I also believe that I'm properly using the `pageToken` field to iterate through the pages, so it doesn't seem to be an issue with that.  I've tried setting `maxResults` to `5` and I end up with 8 pages of 5 users.

```js
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var youtube = google.youtube("v3");

var googleScanRunning = false;
var googleClient;
var googleNextKey = undefined;

const googleConfig = {
  clientId: "<MY_CLIENT_ID>",
  clientSecret: "<MY_CLIENT_SECRET>",
  redirect: "http://localhost:3030/oauth2callback" 
};

/* create a URL that will redirect the user to Google Authentication */
/* once the user goes to the URL and signs in, the OAuth2 token
 * is passed to the /oauth2callback/ endpoint, which calls
 * SetCredentials with the token */
function GetGoogleRedirect() {
  var clientSecret = googleConfig.clientSecret;
  var clientId = googleConfig.clientId;
  var redirectUrl = googleConfig.redirect;
  googleClient = new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  var authUrl = googleClient.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"]
  });

  return authUrl;

}

async function doGoogleScan() {

  let request = await youtube.subscriptions.list({
    part: "snippet,contentDetails,id",
    auth: googleClient,
    mySubscribers: true,
    maxResults: 50,
    pageToken: googleNextKey
  });

  /* end of list? restart at front */
  if (request.data.items.length == 0) {
    googleNextKey = undefined;
  } else {
    googleNextKey = request.data.nextPageToken;
  }

  for (let i in request.data.items) {
    let entry = request.data.items[i];
    let ID = entry.snippet.channelId;

    console.log("sub: " + ID);
  }

  console.log("===== PAGE COMPLETE =====");
  
  /* go to the next page, or back to the beginning */
  setTimeout(doGoogleScan, 3000);

} 

/* code is received from localhost:3030/oauth2callback/ and passed here */
async function SetCredentials(code) {
  googleClient.getToken(code, async function(err, token) {
    googleClient.credentials = token;
    
    if (!googleScanRunning) { 
      googleScanRunning = true;
      doGoogleScan();
    }

  });
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong that's making it so new subscribers are not detected?  The code above works just fine, `googleClient` is properly initialized and authenticated elsewhere.

Comment: I don't see you looping to do a second request with the `nextPageToken`.

Comment: `doGoogleScan` is called repeatedly by `setInterval`.  I should have clarified this.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Sure.  I updated the code to include more context.

Comment: I'd recommend to file a bug report to Google directly, through its [own issue tracker site](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Also, I'd recommend to try `if (request.data.nextPageToken) ...` instead of `if (request.data.items.length == 0) ...`.